# what is the headword in this sentence?

Tags: syntax, english, phrase-structure

"**Before the Saturday kidnappings, professional associations and businesses in Port-au-Prince** had called for an indefinite strike."

How many noun groups are in the bold clause? and what is the headword?

Comment: Mramohmd, we do expect on this site that you show your own work. Could you [edit] your question to explain your thoughts and where you get stuck *exactly*?

Comment: The head of a clause is always a verb phrase, and the head of a verb phrase is always a verb, so the head word of your sentence is the verb "had".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many approaches to syntax would view the finite auxiliary verb *had* as the head word of the entire sentence. The part in bold arguably contains four nominal groups (*the Saturday kidnappings*, *professional associations*, *businesses in Port-au-Prince*, and *Port-au-Prince*). The first part in bold is an adjunct prepositional phrase, i.e. *before the Saturday kidnappings*, and the second part in bold (after the comma) is the subject of the sentence, i.e. *professional associations and businesses in Port-au-Prince*. There are five nominal groups present (i.e. NPs or DPs depending on your theoretical assumptions) in the entire sentence. The head word of the prepositional phrase is the preposition *before*. The subject nominal group consists of two conjoined smaller nominal groups, i.e. *professional associations* and *businesses in Port-au-Prince*. The heads of these two nominal groups are *associations* and *businesses*, respectively, on an NP analysis.

Comment: *kidnappings*; *associations*; *businesses*; and *Port-au-Prince* would also be noun groups, even though they consist of only one word. Whether *Saturday* is to be included is debatable since it is used as an adjective.

Comment: Viewing _kidnappings_ alone as a nominal group is problematic because it is part of the compound noun, i.e. _Saturday kidnappings_. Doing so would necessitate that one also view _Saturday_ as a nominal group. One could debate that analysis, for it depends on how one wants to view compounds. But your right about Port-au-Prince being a nominal group. I will correct my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, if you take it as a lexicalized compound noun it is just *Saturday kidnappings* that is the NP. But at least historically the structure would have been [NP [AdjP Saturday] [NP kidnappings]].

Comment: Why would one ever want to view _Saturday_ as an adjective? In a compound perhaps it functions like an adjective, but it is clearly a noun in most environments.

Comment: No matter the analysis of compounds, *kidnappings*, *associations*, and *businesses* are all NPs.

Comment: If one assumes the DP analysis of nominal groups, you're right. If one assumes the traditional NP analysis of nominal groups, though, they are not NPs, but rather they are Ns.